# Changing < to " but leave << alone in Vim

Tags: substitute, filetype-c++

I have a .cpp file in which I would like to change all less-than symbols to double quotes but maintain any instances of double-greater-than symbols, i.e. change < to " while leaving all occurrences of << alone.

I am very new to vim and as such am still trying to figure out the best way to replace characters in situations like this.

Comment: So far I have tried the command :g/\(<<\)\@<!</s/</" but the result comes out like this:
<
<<
<
becomes:
"
"<
"

Comment: Maybe this? `%s/\(^\|[^<]\)<\($\|[^<]\)/\1"\2/g`

Comment: @JoãoA.Toledo That worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoA.Toledo make that an answer! Id suggest the very-magic flag `\v` to cut down on the pattern noise though.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make an answer out of my comment above: you could substitute all ocurences of `<` without a successor `<`:

```
%s/\(^\|[^<]\)<\($\|[^<]\)/\1"\2/g
```

Or, using the very-magic flag, as suggested by @d-ben-knoble:

```
%s/\v(^|[^<])\<($|[^<])/\1"\2/g
```

That means:

`%s`  substitute in all lines

`/\v` starts search pattern and use `very-magic` flag, so we don't need to escape some characters

`(^|[^<])` searches for a start of line (`^`) or one characters that is different from `<`

`\<` then searches for a `<` (the escape character here is needed)

`($|[^<])` and finally searches for an end-of-line or a character that is different from `<`

`/\1"\2/g` and replaces all the findings with the first character, then `"` and the second character.

Answer (score 1):

### Use lookarounds

I think the simplest `:substitute` command might be to use lookarounds:

```
:%s/<\@<!<<\@!/"/g
```

This replaces every `<` character that is neither preceded nor followed by another `<` character.

### How it works

It uses a `:substitute` command (See `:help :substitute`) to replace strings that match the regular expression `<\@<!<<\@!` with `"` characters.

The regular expression is reasonably simple when broken down. It consists of three parts:

```
:%s/<\@<!<<\@!/"/g
         ^
         1
```

In the middle is a single `<` character. This is what we want to match.

```
:%s/<\@<!<<\@!/"/g
    ^^^^^
      2
```

Before that is: `<\@<!`. This is a second `<` character followed by Vim's atom for negative lookbehind: `\@<!`, which means that our central `<` will only be matched if we *didn't* match a `<` here.

```
:%s/<\@<!<<\@!/"/g
          ^^^^
            3
```

At the end we have: `<\@!`. This is a third `<`, this time followed by Vim's atom for negative lookahead: `\@!`:our `<` will only be matched if it is *not* followed by a `<`.

See `:help \@!` and `:help \@<!` for more details of Vim's negative lookaround atoms.

Comment: Ah I see what's happening there. I tried something very similar to this before, but didn't use `\@!` when dealing with the third <. This seems like a clean way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to match single `<`, you have to consider behind and after character, which might also be start of line or end of line. An alternative is to match both of them, use `\=` to deal with `<<`

```
%s/\V<<\|</\=submatch(0)=='<'?'"':'<<'/g
```

- `\V<<\|<` match `<<` or `<` if no `<<` exists
- `\=submatch(0)=='<'?'"':'<<'` replace `<` with `"`, `<<` with `<<`

  - `\=` substitute with an expression, check `:h sub-replace-expression`
  - `submatch(0)` the whole matched text in current `:substitute` command.
  - `submatch(0)=='<'?'"':'<<'` return `"` for `<`, `<<` for `<<`

Comment: I don't think you need the very-nomagic switch `\V`: your expression works without it. Also, I'd argue that `<<\?` is simpler than `<<\|<\` but I guess that's a matter of preference.

Comment: Thanks,  `<<\?` is simpler, it's better then `|`.  I add  `\v` or `\V` to all my `regex`,  their rule is simple.